# Detect drag canceled JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

In my JavaFX application I need to detect when the user canceled a drag action (like `right clicking` while dragging or pressing `ESC` button while dragging). I tried to listen on every `DragEvent` type on my main `window`, like `DRAG_EXITED_TARGET` or `DRAG_EXITED` but those are fired even if the cursor moves to another `Node`... I'm unable to narrow it to the single event of canceling the drag action. 
I read that `event.getGestureTarget() == null` could mean that the user canceled the action, but it's also `null` when it leaves to another `Node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working for me by adding a `PropertyChangeListener` to a window's `focusedProperty`. When the user cancels the drag action, my `window` is losing the focus so this works for me.